# libjpeg image distortion issues

Tags: c, image, arm, jpeg, libjpeg

I am attempting to compress a RGB image into a JPEG using libjpeg from ijg. In the end the idea is to take an image with a image sensor and compress the data into a JPEG on an ARM Cortex M3 controller; however, for testing purposes I've been using BMP files converted to RGB .data files using GIMP.

I've been able to successfully compress the RGB data into a JPEG image on an SD card using the controller and libjpeg, but I am seeing a distorted line across the image using this method, and I am unsure what is causing this, and how to fix it.

Here's the compressed JPEG image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlzJr.jpg

Here's the source BMP image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLCXG.png

Here's relevant code snippets:

```
static uint8_t* _pucImageSrc ;
static uint8_t* _pucImageDst ;
static uint8_t*_pucCapturedBuf;

uint8_t _compress_image_jpg(SJPEGTest *pImage, sdCardDataHandler *datahandler){
    SJpegData sJpegData;

    _pucImageDst=malloc(datahandler->sourceSize);
    _pucCapturedBuf = datahandler->sourcePtr;

    pImage->dwTimeC=getTicks();
    JpegData_Init( &sJpegData ) ;
    JpegData_SetSource( &sJpegData, _pucCapturedBuf, datahandler->sourceSize) ;
    JpegData_SetDestination( &sJpegData, _pucImageDst, datahandler->sourceSize ) ;
    JpegData_SetDimensions( &sJpegData, 512, 384, 3 ) ;
    JpegData_SetParameters( &sJpegData, 25, JPG_DATA_RGB, JPG_METHOD_IFAST ) ;

        if ( ijg_compress( &sJpegData ) == 0 ){
            pImage->dwTimeC=1+getTicks()-pImage->dwTimeC;
            pImage->dwFinalLength=sJpegData.dwDstLength;
            pImage->dwTimeD=getTicks();
        } else {
             return JPEG_CONVERSION_ERRORED;    
        }

    datahandler->destSize = sJpegData.dwDstLength;
    datahandler->destPtr = _pucImageDst;

    return JPEG_CONVERSION_COMPLETE;
}

extern uint32_t ijg_compress( SJpegData* pData ){
    struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo ;
    struct my_error_mgr       jerr ;
    JSAMPROW row_pointer ;          /* pointer to a single row */

    assert( pData != NULL ) ;

    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error( &jerr.pub ) ;
    if(setjmp(jerr.setjmp_buffer)){
        jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);
        return 1;
    }
    jpeg_create_compress( &cinfo ) ;
    jpeg_mem_dest( &cinfo, &(pData->pucDst), (unsigned long*)&(pData->dwDstLength) ) ;

    cinfo.image_width      = pData->dwWidth ;
    cinfo.image_height     = pData->dwHeight ;
    cinfo.input_components = pData->dwBPP ;
    cinfo.in_color_space   = pData->eInput ;

    jpeg_set_defaults( &cinfo ) ;
    cinfo.dct_method = pData->eMethod ;
    jpeg_set_quality( &cinfo, pData->dwQuality, true ) ;
    jpeg_start_compress( &cinfo, true ) ;

    while ( cinfo.next_scanline < cinfo.image_height )
    {
        row_pointer = (JSAMPROW) &pData->pucSrc[cinfo.next_scanline*cinfo.image_width*cinfo.input_components] ;
        jpeg_write_scanlines( &cinfo, &row_pointer, 1 ) ;
    }

    jpeg_finish_compress( &cinfo ) ;
    jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Did you check decoder examples?

Comment: In libjeg's example.c I've been looking at the write_JPEG_file function. Some of the function calls in the above example appear to come from the libjpeg library taken from Atmel's SAM3S PIRRD jpeg compression application note & library. I am not using a SAM3S controller, rather I am using a SAM3U controller. From both of these references I have gotten to the point described in the post.

Comment: It looks like your source image data is the source of the problem. Any corruption of the compressed data would likely cause the rest of the image from that point on to be completely useless. If you're not using restart markers, then there would be almost no way to resynchronize after an error. It looks like something is writing on top of your image buffer after you load the bmp file into memory.

Comment: I'll attempt to verify if we are corrupting the data after it's loaded into memory, but I doubt this is the case as we are running an external RAM chip which is solely being used as the heap for the raw data read in and the compressed jpeg data from libjpeg, and is being allocated via malloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having to port libjpeg to a new controller that did not have a certain library installed I was able to determine the issue. Some memory was not being free'd correctly due me at one point replacing free() calls with membag_free(), then reverting back to free() but missing one call. Doh! Thanks for the help!